# Tuples with restrictions

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, combinatorics

**SHORT VERSION**

Given `2t` `Range`s, each of length `len`, what is the fastest way of finding the tuples created from these `Range`s that satisfy the constraints in the 5-point list below? `2t` is in the range 10-15, `len` is typically 5 or 7. Filtering the output of `Tuples` is not viable because that output is often much too large to hold in RAM.

**LONG VERSION**

**Background**

While working on finding the constrained maxima of some functions in `2*t` variables, I am evaluating the functions over a part of a square `2t`-dimensional grid. The part of the grid I'm interested in satisfies the following constraints: Assume `t == n1 +  n2` with `n1 <= n2`, and denote the `2t` variables `x[i]`, `i = Range[2t]`. Then

1. `x[i] <= x[i + 1]` for `1 <= i <= n1 - 1`
2. `x[i] <= x[i + 1]` for `n1 + 1 <= i <= t`
3. `x[i]^2 + x[i + t]^2 <= x[n1 + 1]^2` for `n1 + 2 <= i <= t`
4. `x[n1 + 1] <= 0`
5. `x[n1 + 1 + t] == 0`

During my code, I am "zooming" in on parts of the grid, so that at a particular time I may have the following ranges available for the coordinates:

```
SeedRandom[0];
n1 = 2;
n2 = 3;
t = n1 + n2;
len = 4;
ranges = Range[#, # + len] & /@ 
   RandomInteger[{-10, 10 - len}, 2 t - 2];
ranges = Insert[
  Insert[ranges, Range[#, # + len] &@RandomInteger[{-10, 0 - len}], 
   1], {0}, n1 + 1 + t]
```

With this, constraints 4 and 5 are already satisfied.

**The two approaches**

In order to find the tuples that satisfy the rest of the constraints, I may either

1. create all tuples with `Tuples` and then filter them according to the constraints, or
2. I can try to bake in the constraints from the start, perhaps using `Table` with restrictions on iterator values.

For 1., I have tried:

```
tup = Tuples[ranges];
cons3ok = Pick[tup,
  With[{squared = Transpose[tup^2]},
   Plus @@ (
     UnitStep@
      Chop@Table[
        squared[[n1 + 1]] - squared[[i]] - squared[[t + i]], {i, 
         n1 + 2, t}])
   ], n2 - 1];
valid = Select[
  cons3ok, (OrderedQ[Take[#, {1, n1}]] && 
     OrderedQ[Take[#, {n1 + 1, t}]]) &];
```

This works well for small `t` because `Tuples` is so incredibly fast, but as `t` grows `Tuples` suffers from the curse of dimensionality, so I use up all my RAM storing the intermediate `tup`.

For 2. I made recursive use of `Table`; it's long, but the constraints are easy to "read off":

```
recTable[ind_] :=
 Which[
  ind == 1, 
  Table[recTable[ind + 1], {x[ind], ranges[[1, 1]], 
    ranges[[1, -1]]}],
  ind <= n1, 
  Table[recTable[ind + 1], {x[ind], Max[ranges[[ind, 1]], x[ind - 1]],
     ranges[[ind, -1]]}],
  ind == n1 + 1, 
  Table[recTable[ind + 1], {x[ind], ranges[[ind, 1]], 
    ranges[[ind, -1]]}],
  ind <= t, 
  Table[recTable[ind + 1], {x[ind], Max[ranges[[ind, 1]], x[ind - 1]],
     Min[ranges[[ind, -1]], -x[n1 + 1]]}],
  ind <= n1 + t, 
  Table[recTable[ind + 1], {x[ind], ranges[[ind, 1]], 
    ranges[[ind, -1]]}],
  ind <= 2 t, 
  Table[recTable[ind + 1], {x[ind], 
    Max[ranges[[ind, 1]], Ceiling[-Sqrt[x[n1 + 1]^2 - x[ind - t]^2]]],
     Min[ranges[[ind, -1]], Floor[Sqrt[x[n1 + 1]^2 - x[ind - t]^2]]]}],
  ind == 2 t + 1, Array[x, 2 t]
  ]

valid2 = Flatten[recTable[1], 2 t - 1];
```

This should not eat up all my RAM as quickly as 1., but it's a lot slower than using `Tuples`...

**QUESTION**

How can I improve either of the methods (or create a new one altogether) such that I don't spend all my RAM, and still get a result without waiting for days? I'm hoping for results with `n1 = 3`, `n2 = 5`.

Also, how can `Tuples` be so much faster than using `Table` or `Outer`? Am I messing something up?

Comment: Might `CylindricalDecomposition` help?

Comment: I have a look at this, but I'm put of trying further as I think that there are mistakes in your problem specification.  E.g. what is `tot`?

Comment: @mikado, sorry for the typos, corrected now I think